# How to check if array contains objects

Tags: javascript

I have array, created from json:

```
var array = [{"name":"name1","group":"group1","id":"123", ...},
{"name":"name2","group":"group2","id":"456", ...},
{"name":"name3","group":"group1","id":"789", ...}];
```

After I get another array:

```
var array1 = [{"name":"name1","group":"group1","id":"123", ...},
{"name":"name4","group":"group1","id":"987", ...}]
```

I need to push items from second array into first, but how can I check if first array contains objects from second array?

Each object in array contain more property and some of them are created dynamically so I can't check for example by `indexOf()`. All solutions that I found works only with simple objects like `Int`. It will be great if I could check by property "id" for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` first

```
var newObj = {"name":"name2","group":"group2","id":"456"};
var value = array.find( s => s.id == newObj.id );
```

Now push if the `value` is not found

```
if ( !value )
{
   array.push( newObj ) 
}
```

Comment: Or use `array.some`.

Comment: Yes, if only a boolean is required. However, find can be useful if existing value has to be updated.

Comment: @gurvinder372 That works, thank you. I expected that solution must be easy, but not expected that so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

(More generic)you can do this one line using following (which will add all object which is not in array).

```
array.concat(array1.filter(x=>!array.find(s=>s.id==x.id)));
```

```js
var array = [{"name":"name1","group":"group1","id":"123"},
             {"name":"name2","group":"group2","id":"456" },
             {"name":"name3","group":"group1","id":"789"}];

var array1 = [{"name":"name1","group":"group1","id":"123"},
              {"name":"name4","group":"group1","id":"987"}];

array=array.concat(array1.filter(x=>!array.find(s=>s.id==x.id)));
console.log(array);
```